# How do I release a Maven project being built using a Jenkins multi-configuration job

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have attempted to find an answer to this question in the suggested 
questions that appear above, and via Google, but I cannot find a resolution.

I have a maven project, which when built, activates the correct profile for
the platform it is being built on.

The windows profile, downloads the source code and builds the Windows binaries into an artifact, with a classifier:

- myproj-version-SNAPSHOT-w64.jar

The linux profile, downloads the source code and builds the Linux binaries 
into an artifact, with a classifier:

- myproj-version-SNAPSHOT-lx86_64.jar

It also build the java code artifact:

- myproj-version-SNAPSHOT.jar

I have set this up as a multi-configuration job in Jenkins 2, with the axis
simply containing the labels for Linux and Windows nodes. This builds both
correctly, and has deployed them into Nexus.

However, the option, Release Maven Project is not available as an option on
this job, and I am not sure exactly how to release the binaries. With a 
Maven Jenkins job, it is obviously available as an option.

How do I setup my multi-configuration job in Jenkins 2, to do a release.
I imagine it will need to do the following:

On the master node:

1. clean the workspace then pull the git repository
2. update the POM to the release version (strip -SNAPSHOT)
3. push the change and tag the release (myproj-version)
4. trigger the builds on the axis node

On the Windows node:

1. clean the workspace then pull the git repository - this will be the
   release build that was tagged
2. build and deploy the 1 artifact

On the Linux node:

1. clean the workspace then pull the git repository - this will be the
   release build that was tagged
2. build and deploy the 2 artifacts

On the master node:

1. update POM for next development version (version +1 and add
   -SNAPSHOT)
2. push the above change to the repository

**Update**: There is also now an issue with Nexus. The windows node finishes 
first, and deploys its 1 artifact. The linux node finishes, and deploys its
2 artifacts. For a short while all 3 artifacts (which share the same group
and artifact id), are present. Then the windows artifact is removed.

**Update 2**: The reason Nexus is removing the windows artifact is the
maven-metadata.xml that maven publishes with the artifacts. The one published from
windows contains the 1 artifact and the pom. The linux contains the other
2 artifacts, and overwrites the first one. Nexus thus cleans away SNAPSHOT
artifacts it believes are no longer built/required.

### Summary

There are now 2 questions here:

1. how do i merge the maven-metadata.xml from the 2 nodes
2. how do i release the artifacts

Thanks,

Comment: rather than using profiles, why not set this up as a multi-module project (one module per platform)? That way you could use the maven release plugin without any special settings

Comment: You still have to have profiles to activate the correct module for the platform. And you still have to build the project on separate nodes, using a multi-configuration project. So the problem will still exist.

Comment: why? can't you build all platforms on the same server?

Comment: Because it is building native code. One on Linux one on Windows.

Comment: ah okay. then never mind